# Running Android in ubuntu with out netbean or eclipse

Tags: android, command-line

I have been learning Android under windows 7 with netbeans. I used netbeans IDE for opening a android project, debug, run. For making any change in the code i used gvim. Now i have changed my OS with ubuntu LTS (10.04). I need to  depend only on command line compilation due to some reasons. So i can not have either eclipse or netbeans.

I have installed everything correctly. When I give Android in the command line the emulator shows up..I have created hello world with command line. I followed these links..

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html

I install the app (.apk) and run through emulator. It is ruing for the first time. But when i change any code then its not as easy like the netbeans IDE button clicks like "build and run". When I run again (`command: ant debug / adb install .apk`) it says that it has been already install. I also wanted to run the sample programs (comes along with android download) through cmd line and run it through emulator. But when I give my command "ant debug" no build file found because those sample have only `/res` and `/src` with main fist xml.

Is there any easy way to compile and run programs with command line? For a very simple change to see the output do i have to go through all these long command line process?

Comment: Thanks for all the guidence below. I have tried the following..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong, you need read help of adb command
adb install -r your-apk

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate a build.xml and use ant to compile your code following the instructions [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html). You can dig deeper in those links to learn more about commandline builds. Then you can load it on handset using adb commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this from your project folder.

```
android update project --path .
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all a bit outdated, as nowadays you use gradle. If you still use ant, you can try this instead of your commands ("`ant debug / adb install .apk`")

```
ant debug install
```

This combines both of your commands and also does a reinstall if the package already exists.

If you use gradle, you can do

```
gradle installDebug
```

(this is from [a question about how to do this on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17328061/1587329). Upvote there too, if you use this)