# Can you deploy to a device via Gradle from the command line

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, gradlew

What the question says really - can you issue any commands directly to gradlew via the command line to build, package and deploy to a device?

Comment: `gradle tasks` is helpful to see the out of the box tasks - which includes installing (but not starting as stated below)

Comment: Command line is not IDE specific, .i.e. this way would work from Android Studio or Eclipse-based IDE

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
$ gradle installDebug
```

This will push the debug build apk to device, but you have to manually start the application.

Comment: As below, it's been renamed to "gradle installDefaultFlavorDebug"

Comment: @durka42 This is only the case if you use flavors

Comment: I'd say ./gradlew iD instead of gradle iD

Comment: Is that possible to run this command inside installed Gradle Plugin on Eclipse? I get this error: Task 'installDebug' not found in root project 'blahblah'.

Answer (score 76):

Since you are using Gradle, you could simple add your own task in **build.gradle**

```
task appStart(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDebug') {
    // linux 
    commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.example/.MyActivity'

    // windows
    // commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.example/.MyActivity'      
}
```

then call it in your project root

`$ gradle appStart`

**Update:**

If you are using `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"`, add `.debug` to the **appId only** but leave the activity untouched:

`'com.example.debug/com.example.MyActivity'`

Comment: In addition, the last parameter should be `'com.your.packagename/.path.relative.to.your.packagename.MyActivity'` instead of `'com.example/.MyActivity'` if your Activity is not in the root of your package.

Answer (score 68):

**1. Build project, install generated apk to device**

```
# at the root dir of project
$ gradle installDebug
```

**2. Open app on device**

```
$ adb shell am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname
```

Comment: alias arun="gradle installDebug; adb shell am start -n com.example.app/.activity.MainActivity"

Comment: I cannot select installDebug in gradle. There is no suitable task. Has it been renamed?

Comment: @JonasGröger it seems to have been renamed to installDefaultFlavorDebug

Comment: @rps_deepan Could you rename the task because it has been renamed?

Comment: `alias arun="./gradlew installDebug && adb shell am start -n com.example.package/.LauncherActivity"` #Runs step2 Only when Step 1 is success

Comment: It's worth noting, the task may be different if you have build variants (as shown in the lower left of Android Studio). For me the command was `./gradlew installDevDebug`. This could change the package too: `am start -n com.example.example_dev/com.example.example.MainActivity`. This stumped me for a while.

Answer (score 7):

One line sentence:

**Build project & Install generated apk & Open app on device**

```
$ ./gradlew installDebug && adb shell am start -n com.example/.activities.MainActivity
```

Answer (score 7):

There are three commands to accomplish this:

1. `./gradlew assembleDebug #To build the project`
2. `adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk #To install it to the device`
3. `adb shell am start -n $PACKAGE/$PACKAGE.$ACTIVITY #To launch the application in the device`, where $PACKAGE is the development package and $ACTIVITY is the activity to be launched (the launcher activity).

I've been writing a [bash script to do this](https://github.com/mhbrhm/roya), with other few features.

Answer (score 5):

Build -> uninstall old verion -> install new version -> run application.

```
echo "Build application" && ./gradlew clean build && 
echo "Uninstall application" && adb uninstall [application package] && 
echo "Install application" && adb -d install app/build/outputs/apk/<build type>/[apk name].apk echo "Run application" && 
adb shell am start -n [application package]/.[application name]
```

Or if you want install and run application in debug type.

```
./gradlew installDebug && adb shell am start -n [application package]/.[application name]
```

Comment: Thanks. @alexander-polomodov

Answer (score 4):

A more flexible way to do it is by using monkey:

```
task runDebug (type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDebug') {
    commandLine android.getAdbExe().toString(), "shell",
        "monkey",
        "-p", "your.package.name.debugsuffix",
        "-c", "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER", "1"
}
```

Some advantages to this method:

- `getAdbExe` doesn't require adb to be on the path and uses the adb version from the sdk pointed to in `local.properties`.
- The `monkey` tool allows you to send a launcher intent, so you aren't required to know the name of your activity.

Comment: You could instead execute `adb shell am start your.package.name.debugsuffix\.Activity`

Comment: But what if you don't know your activity's name?

Comment: Then you shouldn't be writing the build file.

Comment: I think its a really bad idea for the build file know explicitly which Activity to run...seems like something separation of concerns goes against. One simple reason - if you rename/move your Activity file, this now requires a build file change. Additionally, intents seem like a better api to run against than a file - I could write a gradle extension that adds default intents and ways to run them, version it, and never need to know anybody's class names. Hard coding is never the right answer.

Comment: This answer also lacks a way to find the root package - I'd like to get rid of the package name too - e.g. discover it from the manifest instead.

Comment: @0xcaff using `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1` you don't need to know the activity.

Answer (score 2):

```
task appStart(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDebug') {
    commandLine android.adbExe, 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.example/.MyActivity'
}
```

Comment: Best solution of run

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this task to be able to install and also open the application on the device. Since I had multiple `buildTypes` and `flavors` with different application ids, it was not feasible to hard code the package name. So I wrote it like this instead:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    task "open${variant.name.capitalize()}" {
        dependsOn "install${variant.name.capitalize()}"

        doLast {
            exec {
                commandLine "adb shell monkey -p ${variant.applicationId} -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1".split(" ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would give you `open{variant}` for every `install{variant}` task you already have.