# Android Studio rebuilds project every time when I hit run

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

yes, i switched to Android Studio finally. But every time when i want to start my application on my nexus, it rebuilds the whole project, also when i did not make any changes in the code. Is that normal? May I have to uncheck any option in the settings?

When you leave the code unchanged in eclipse, it'll starts the app immediately on my handset.

I'm using the latest version 0.2.9

Comment: I have this behavior also

Comment: Do you know how to speed up the install process on a real device when you hit run?

Comment: Not really - sometimes it can help to work directly with gradle on the command line - like this ppost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326162/can-you-deploy-to-a-device-via-gradle-from-the-command-line-in-android-studio

Comment: One other thing - if nothing has changed, and you just want to debug, you can just re-attach to the process inside of android studio

Comment: Ok thanks for the command line hint. I tried it. I couldn't see any speed up...It took as long as before...about 30 sec. When starting without any changes to the code it takes about 10-15 sec. It takes nearly twice the time as on Eclipse.