# How do I use handlebars-asset-pipeline with Grails?

Tags: grails, handlebars.js, asset-pipeline

I'm close to giving up here -- there's roughly 5 different repositories with different versions of handlebars-asset-pipeline with different instructions, and I can't get any of them to work.

I'm using Grails 3.1.1 with the default build.gradle created by init-app, added handlebars-asset-pipeline 2.7 to both the buildscript and normal dependencies, and put a foo.hbs file into grails-app/assets.

Now, when running `gradlew compileAssets`, the templates get compiled correctly, so the plugin is doing *something*, but I was expecting it to also work when running the application via `grails run-app`. Is it wrong of me to expect that? If not, can someone be so kind as to give me a working example of how to integrate the template precompiler?

Answer (score 1):

I find specifying assets instead of runtime is the thing that trips me up. I can get it to work adding the following

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
     ...
     classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.6"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline'


runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.3"
assets 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:handlebars-asset-pipeline:2.14.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use it but since you use Gradle I'm quite sure you can add it as your own task with `dependsOn: 'compileAssets'`. Check out [example for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21992166/2166188).

Comment: True, but that puts the compiled assets into the build/ folder as opposed to compiling them on-the-fly, which is what I'd expect the plugin to do (but that might be my mistaken assumption).